# error during mysql deployment in kubernetes for FireFly III installation

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

followed https://docs.firefly-iii.org/installation/k8n
Did some extra customization to the pvc's to make them bind to my nfs pv's.
All going smooth so far. But the mysql pod wont come up and gets into a CrashLoopBackOff.

Describing the mysql pod:

```
~/kubernetes$ kubectl describe pod firefly-iii-mysql-67bfb68cf9-6gm9l
Name:         firefly-iii-mysql-67bfb68cf9-6gm9l
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         ommitted
Start Time:   Fri, 30 Oct 2020 15:09:29 +0000
Labels:       app=firefly-iii
              pod-template-hash=67bfb68cf9
              tier=mysql
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.32.0.4
IPs:
  IP:           10.32.0.4
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/firefly-iii-mysql-67bfb68cf9
Containers:
  mysql:
    Container ID:   docker://7c0e5920d4e1cb3ce98308e0c02d4a98bc9926b828c50496b8d8b3486245dcb9
    Image:          mysql:5.6
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://mysql@sha256:8875725ff152f77e47a563661ea010b4ca9cea42d9dda897fb565ca224e83de2
    Port:           3306/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    141
      Started:      Fri, 30 Oct 2020 15:25:48 +0000
      Finished:     Fri, 30 Oct 2020 15:25:50 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  8
    Environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'db_password' in secret 'firefly-iii-secrets-kkcdcb696c'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/mysql from mysql-persistent-storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-k9zt4 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  mysql-persistent-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  mysql-pv-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-k9zt4:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-k9zt4
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                  ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  18m (x2 over 18m)     default-scheduler  persistentvolumeclaim "mysql-pv-claim" not found
  Normal   Scheduled         18m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/firefly-iii-mysql-67bfb68cf9-6gm9l to domm-lnx-02
  Normal   Pulled            16m (x5 over 18m)     kubelet            Container image "mysql:5.6" already present on machine
  Normal   Created           16m (x5 over 18m)     kubelet            Created container mysql
  Normal   Started           16m (x5 over 18m)     kubelet            Started container mysql
  Warning  BackOff           3m16s (x73 over 18m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

From the logs I get this:

```
~/kubernetes$ kubectl logs firefly-iii-mysql-67bfb68cf9-6gm9l
2020-10-30 15:25:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.6.50-1debian9 started.
2020-10-30 15:25:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-10-30 15:25:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.6.50-1debian9 started.
2020-10-30 15:25:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2020-10-30 15:25:50 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-10-30 15:25:50 0 [Note] Ignoring --secure-file-priv value as server is running with --bootstrap.
2020-10-30 15:25:50 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.50) starting as process 52 ...
2020-10-30 15:25:50 52 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/firefly-iii-mysql-67bfb68cf9-6gm9l.lower-test
2020-10-30 15:25:50 52 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/firefly-iii-mysql-67bfb68cf9-6gm9l.lower-test
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2020-10-30 15:25:50 52 [ERROR] Aborting

2020-10-30 15:25:50 52 [Note] Binlog end
2020-10-30 15:25:50 52 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

pod creation yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: firefly-iii-mysql
  labels:
    app: firefly-iii
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: firefly-iii
      tier: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: firefly-iii
        tier: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: firefly-iii-secrets
              key: db_password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

I had some trouble with my pvc's at first, but that seems to be resolved now. The firefly-iii main pod seems to be working just fine, with a similar pv-pvc setup. I had to recreate the whole deployment a couple of times. But now I am stuck with this permission error. I am not sure how to fix it and I could not find much useful anywhere about this...

I hope someone here can point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Problem was with the nfs permissions. Had to set them to "map all users to admin" on the nfs host. Now my deployment can actually edit files there... Which is something mysql likes ;)